# Insert values from form boxes into last record of table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a very large sub routine that opens forms and insert values into text boxes and saves changes. it works, but it inserts these values into random rows and not the newest record on the table. I have also tried a INSERT INTO VALUES query which does the same thing (through VBA and regular SQL query). Is it possible to add these values to the final/first row of the corresponding table? Primary key's are autonumber.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "dentalheader", acNormal , , , , acHidden
    Forms!dentalheader!yeartype.Value = "Benefit"
    Forms!dentalheader!term.Value = "80"
    Forms!dentalheader!personmax.Value = "99999"

INSERT INTO dentalheader (each, overallmax, personmax,) 
VALUES (true, '10000', '99999', )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a datetime field and insert Now:

```
INSERT INTO dentalheader (timestamp, each, overallmax, personmax) 
VALUES (Now(), true, '10000', '99999' )
```

Then, for display, sort on timestamp.

Comment: Will it not override the last one done each time? My tables are linked so I have to edit this on the server before I can test.

Comment: How could it? It inserts a new record. And a database is not a spreadsheet; there is not "first" or "last" record.